# Função que retorna o menor número primo em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, números

Estava escrevendo um código em Python que recebesse um número e retornasse o primeiro número primo menor ou igual a esse número.

Criei uma função chamada `maior_primo`, que faz o seguinte:

- `maior_primo(100)` - retorna 97.
- `maior_primo(23)` - retorna 23.

O código funciona, mas acho que ficou muito grande, pois eu precisei criar outras duas funções adicionais, alguém pode me mostrar uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso? O código segue abaixo:

```
def primos_maiores_que_10(n):

    i=2
    while i<10:
        if(n%i==0):
            return "Não é primo."
        i=i+1
    return 1

def primos_menores_que_10(n):
    if n==2 or n==3 or n==5 or n==7:
        return 1
    else:
        return "Não é primo."


def maior_primo(n):
    x=0
    while n<2:
        n=int(input("Digite o valor de n>= 2."))

    while n>1:
        if n>10:
            x=primos_maiores_que_10(n)
            if x==1:
                return n
            n=n-1
        else:
            x=primos_menores_que_10(n)
            if x==1:
                return n
            n=n-1
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Obter a lista de números primos menores que N](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205458/obter-a-lista-de-n%c3%bameros-primos-menores-que-n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em relação à função `maior_primo`, podes reescrevê-la para o seguinte:

```
def maior_primo(n):
    for num in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
        if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)):
            return num

n=int(input("Digite o valor de n>= 2.")) # 100
print(maior_primo(n)) # 97
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/T5fS6h)

Com while:

```
def maior_primo(n):
    while n > 0:
        if all(n%j!=0 for j in range(2,n)):
            return n
        n -= 1

n=int(input("Digite o valor de n>= 2.")) # 100
print(maior_primo(n)) # 97
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/3qqmrt)

Quanto às outras podemos fazer uma alteração ao programa por completo, para ficar mais flexível reutilizável/escalável:

```
def e_primo(num): 
    return all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,num)) 

def primos_menores_que_n(n, start=1):
    for num in range(start,n):
        if e_primo(num):
            yield num    

def maior_primo(n):
    for num in reversed(range(1,n+1)):
        if e_primo(num):
            return num

def primos_maiores_que_n(n, lim):
    return primos_menores_que_n(lim, start=n)

print(list(primos_menores_que_n(10))) # [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
print(list(primos_maiores_que_n(10, 30))) # [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
print(maior_primo(100)) # 97
print(e_primo(10)) # False
print(e_primo(11)) # True
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/Fif4PM)

Answer (score 1):

Usando while (sem expressão geradora):

```
def maior_primo(num):
    while num > 2:
        i = 2
        while True:
            if num % i == 0:
                break
            if i == num - 1:
                return num
            i = i + 1
        num = num - 1
```

Usando for (sem expressão geradora):

```
def maior_primo(num):
    for n in range(num, 2, -1):
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n % i == 0:
                break
            if i == n - 1:
                return n
```

Usando expressão geradora:

```
def maior_primo(num):
    return max( n for n in range(num, 2, -1) if all(n % i!=0 for i in range(2, n)) )
```

Lista:

```
def lst_primos(num):
    primos = [2]
    i = 3

    for _ in range(2, num):
        if all(i % p != 0 for p in primos):
            primos.append(i)
        i += 1

return primos
```

Answer (score -2):

Mais uma opção

```
def maior_primo(n):
    for i in reversed(range(n+1)):
        c = 0
        for j in range(n):
            if i%(j+1) == 0: 
                c += 1
        if c == 2:
            return(i)
        
n=int(input("Digite o valor de n>= 2.")) 
print(maior_primo(n))
```