# Obter a lista de números primos menores que N

Tags: python

Estou com um exercício no qual preciso entrar com um número (N) e calcular com Python quais são os números inferiores a N que são primos.

Esse é o código que tenho agora.

```
num == int(input("Insira um número: ")) 

while num < 0: 
    num == int(input("Valor inválido! Insira um número novamente")) 
    n = 1 c = 0 
    while n < num: 
        if n%1 == 0 and n%n == 0
```

O problema é que tecnicamente todo número dividido por 1 e por ele mesmo tem como resto zero, que condição eu posso usar pra quebrar essa?

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português, para podermos resolver a sua pergunta precisamos ver o código que você está utilizando para resolver o seu problema, está parecendo que você quer o código funcionando sem ter o esforço de pesquisar sobre o assunto.

Comment: Como você checa, matematicamente, se um número é primo ou não?

Comment: num == int(input("Insira um número: "))
while num < 0:
    num == int(input("Valor inválido! Insira um número novamente"))
n = 1
c = 0

while n < num:
    if n%1 == 0 and n%n == 0

Esse é o meu código, o problema é que tecnicamente todo número dividido por 1 e por ele mesmo tem como resto zero, que condição eu posso usar pra quebrar essa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra receber todos os números primos menores que um tal 'n' é simples

Segue o código

```
from math import sqrt
numero = int(input())
aux = 0
aux1 = 0
if numero > 3:
    print(2,'\n',3)      #Coloquei isso aqui, porque  estavam ficando de fora, haha
while numero > 1:
    aux = sqrt(numero)
    aux = int(aux)
    aux1 = 0
    while aux >= 2:
        if numero%aux == 0:
            aux1 += 1
        if aux == 2:
            if aux1 == 0:
                print(numero)
        aux -= 1
    numero -=1
```

Answer (score 8):

Uma das formas de se resolver este exercício é através do [Crivo de Eratóstenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). A ideia, de forma superficial, é obter a lista completa de valores entre 2 e N e remover os que não são primos. O pseudo-código, retirado da fonte supracitada, é:

```
 Input: an integer n > 1.

 Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n,
 initially all set to true.

 for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
   if A[i] is true:
     for j = i2, i2+i, i2+2i, i2+3i, ..., not exceeding n:
       A[j] := false.

 Output: all i such that A[i] is true.
```

Em Python, uma forma de implementarmos é:

```
import math

# Input: an integer n > 1.
N = int(input("N: "))

# Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n, initially all set to true.
A = list(range(2, N))

# for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(N)+1)):

  # if A[i] is true:
  if i in A:

    # for j = i2, i2+i, i2+2i, i2+3i, ..., not exceeding n:
    for j in range(i**2, N, i):

      # A[j] := false.
      if j in A: A.remove(j)

# Output: all i such that A[i] is true.        
print(A)
```

Se entrarmos com um valor 30 para N, obteremos a seguinte saída:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/4XcVgh) ou no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/IIj8/0).

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução diferente:

```
VLimite = 1000
VPrimos = []
VComposto = []
VLimite = VLimite + 1
for i in range(VLimite):
  if (i + 1) == 1:
    VComposto = VComposto + [i + 1]
  if (i + 1) not in VComposto:
    if (i + 1) != VLimite:
      VPrimos = VPrimos + [i + 1]
      if (i + 1) ** 2 > VLimite:
        i = VLimite;
      else: 
        for j in range(i + 1, VLimite, i + 1):
          VComposto = VComposto + [j]
print(VPrimos)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# LISTA OS NÚMEROS PRIMOS ATÉ X(=50) UM ABAIXO DO OUTRO
def primos(x):
for i in range(1, x+1):
    div = 0
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        if(i%j == 0):
            div = div + 1
    if (div == 2):
        print(i)
primos(50)

# LISTA OS NÚMEROS PRIMOS ATÉ X(=50) EM LISTA
numeros = []
def lista(x):
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        div = 0
        for j in range(1, i+1):
             if(i%j == 0):
                 div = div + 1
        if (div == 2):
             numeros.append(i)
   print(numeros)
lista(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução xD:

```
#Criei uma função que calcula se o número é primo ou não
def primo(numero):
    primo = True

    if(numero == 1):
        return False

    for i in range(2,numero):
        if(numero%i == 0):
            primo = False

    if (primo == True):
        return True
    else:
        return False
#Fim da Função

n = int(input("Número: "))

#Loop que printa os números primos excluindo N
for i in range(2,n):
    if(primo(i)):
         print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para retornar quantos primos há entre 2 e n (questão opcional 1 da semana 7 do curso de introdução à ciencia da computação da USP):

```
def n_primos(n):
    n_p = 0
    for i in range(2, n):
        if e_primo(i):
            n_p += 1
        i += 1
    return n_p


def e_primo(n):
    f = 1
    div = 0
    while f <= n:
        if n % f == 0:
            div += 1
        f += 1
    if div > 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True


n_primos(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como range(x,y) inclui o valor de x e pega o imediatamente anterior a y e primo é aquele que só é divisível por 1 e por ele mesmo, eu uso range(2, numero limite). Dessa forma, se algum divisível aparecer, significa que ele não é primo.

```
    def is_prime(numero):
        if any(valor % numero == 0 for valor in range(2, numero)):
            return False
        else:
            return True

    n =  int(input("insira um número: "))
    primos = [ num for num in range(2, n) if is_prime(num)]
```