# Verificar se número é igual à soma dos quadrados de 4 números primos consecutivos

Tags: python, python-3.x, inteiros, números

Preciso fazer um programa em que digito um número e o programa verifica se ele é a soma do quadrado de 4 números primos consecutivos.

Exemplo: 2020 tem que dar 17 ^ 2 + 19 ^ 2 + 23 ^ 2 + 29 ^ 2

Meu código por enquanto está assim:

```
n = int(input("n: "))
num = 2
cont = 0
for div in range(1, num + 1):
    if num % div == 0:
        cont = cont + 1
    num = num + 1
if cont == 2:
    nprimo = True
else:
    nprimo = False
p = 0
while p < n and nprimo:
    n = (num ** 2) + ((num + 1) ** 2) + ((num + 2) ** 2) + ((num + 3) ** 2)
```

Acho que a parte de verificar se o número é primo está correta, o problema está no final, todos os números dão falso. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Seu programa verifica se `num` é primo, e no seu caso num vale 2. Agora a questão pede 4 números primos consecutivos mas você substitui o número lido pela soma dos quadrados de 2, 3, 4 e 5, sendo que 4 certamente não é primo, o que certamente não é o que a questão pede.

Comment: Então aquela parte do if/else basicamente não serviu pra nada?

Answer (score 2):

Se você fizer uma [busca no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+n%C3%BAmeros+primos) encontrará vários algoritmos diferentes para determinar se um número é primo (se buscar no Google então, vai encontrar muitos outros, e verá que o seu algoritmo está muito longe de estar correto).

Mas mesmo que estivesse correto, no final você soma `num ** 2` com `(num + 1) ** 2`, e isso já está errado. Se `num` for primo, então `num + 1` só será primo se `num` for igual a 2. Para qualquer outro número primo, `num + 1` será um número par (e portanto, divisível por 2, e portanto não será primo). O mesmo vale para `num + 2` e `num + 3`, pelo menos um deles não será primo.

Na verdade não existe um intervalo fixo entre números primos. Dado um número primo qualquer, o próximo número primo pode estar a qualquer distância à frente (sobre este assundo sugiro uma lida [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap)), então não tem como somar 1 (ou qualquer outro valor fixo) e com certeza encontrar outro número primo. O jeito é calculá-lo mesmo.

---

<sup>*[Neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/441099/n%c3%bameros-primos-consecutivos-python#comment850836_441126) você disse que não pode usar listas nem funções (**que é uma restrição que deveria estar na pergunta**, assim as pessoas <strike>não perdem tempo escrevendo respostas que não servem</strike> podem se focar na solução mais adequada para o seu caso).*</sup>

Sem usar listas nem funções, uma solução seria guardar 4 números primos consecutivos em variáveis e verificar se a soma dos seus quadrados é igual ao número em questão. Se não for, eu calculo o próximo número primo, faço a soma de novo, e assim vai.

```
import math
n = int(input("n: "))

# já inicio com os 4 primeiros primos
p1, p2, p3, p4 = 2, 3, 5, 7
while True:
    if (p1 ** 2) + (p2 ** 2) + (p3 ** 2) + (p4 ** 2) == n:
        print(f'Encontrei: {p1}, {p2}, {p3} e {p4}')
        break # encontrei, sai do loop

    # não encontrei, buscar o próximo primo
    proximo = p4 + 2 # posso começar a partir de p4
    while proximo <= n: # loop para verificar se "proximo" é primo
        # loop pode ir até raiz quadrada do número: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5811151 
        # range de 2 em 2, para só testar números ímpares
        # como "proximo" é ímpar, não preciso começar o range em 2, pode começar direto no 3
        for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(proximo) + 1), 2):
            if proximo % i == 0:
                primo = False
                break # "proximo" não é primo, sai do for
        else: # se o for não for interrompido pelo break, cai nesse else
            primo = True

        if primo: # atualiza a lista de primos e sai do while interno (volta para o while externo, que verifica a soma dos quadrados)
            p1, p2, p3, p4 = p2, p3, p4, proximo
            break
        else: # não é primo, tentar o próximo número ímpar
            proximo += 2

    if proximo > n: # se já passou de n, é porque não tem
        print(f'{n} não é igual a soma de 4 primos consecutivos ao quadrado')
        break # sai do loop
```

---

Se pudesse usar listas, uma alternativa seria ter uma lista com todos os primos até `n`, e em seguida percorrê-la fazendo a verificação (como fez a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/441126/112052), por exemplo).

O algoritmo abaixo foi retirado [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206144/112052), e é uma implementação do [Crivo de Eratóstenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
import math
n = int(input("n: "))

# criar lista com todos os primos até n (algoritmo do Crivo de Eratóstenes)
primos = list(range(2, n))
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
  if i in primos:
    for j in range(i ** 2, n, i):
      if j in primos:
        primos.remove(j)

# verificar a soma dos quadrados
for i in range(len(primos) - 3):
    if (primos[i] ** 2) + (primos[i + 1] ** 2) + (primos[i + 2] ** 2) + (primos[i + 3] ** 2) == n:
        print(f'Encontrei: {primos[i]}, {primos[i + 1]}, {primos[i + 2]} e {primos[i + 3]}')
        break # encontrei, sai do loop
else:
    print(f'{n} não é igual a soma de 4 primos consecutivos ao quadrado')
```

Evidente que dá para otimizar, pois você não precisa criar a lista com todos os primos até `n`, [poderia ir até a raiz quadrada de `n` dividido por 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3582290), entre outros detalhes. Mas para um exercício, já deve ser o suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
def ehprimo(num,primos):
    for divi in primos:
        if num%divi == 0:
            return False
    return True

num,cont,primos = 2,1,[]
while cont <= 100000:
    if ehprimo(num,primos) == True:
        cont += 1
        print(num)
        primos.append(num)
    num += 1
n = int(input("Informe um número: "))
i = 0
while i < len(primos)-3:
    if n == (primos[i]**2 + primos[i+1]**2 + primos[i+2]**2 + primos[i+3]**2):
        print(n, " = ", primos[i], "^2 + ", primos[i+1], "^2 + ", primos[i+2], "^2 + ", primos[i+3], "^2")
        break
    i += 1
```

Comment: Como é trabalho de faculdade tem algumas coisas que não posso usar por causa de que o professor ainda não passou. Infelizmente, não posso usar listas e nem funções, mas vou tentar algumas ideias aqui.