# Otimização para código que testa se um número é primo

Tags: python

> Olá! Minha pergunta é sobre um código que eu montei, onde o usuário insere um certo número de sua escolha, e o programa irá testar se o mesmo é primo ou não, porém, ele está testando **todos** os números entre dois (2) e o número inserido, o que pode ser bem lento para números de grande porte (os mais indicados para a função do código). Uma solução que tive em mente foi para construir uma espécie de **"Crivo de Eratóstenes"**, onde o programa iria **eliminar todos os múltiplos dos números que já foram testados** (como 2, 3, 5, 7 e 9), para assim, acelerar o processo de verificação do numero.

Entretanto, todas as minhas tentativas para chegar nesse objetivo não vingaram.** Por isso, estou questionando aqui se algum usuário tem algum algoritmo ou método que eu possa adaptar e (consequentemente) aprender com ele. 
**Abaixo está meu código caso seja nescessário (o que provavelmente é):**

```py
import sys

def programa():
    completo = None
    while True:
        if completo == True:
            break
        print()
        print("=" * 55) 
        num = int(input("Digite um número para fazer o teste se o mesmo é primo: "))
        einteiro = isinstance(num, int)
        if num == 1:
            print()
            print("1 é primo.")
            print()
            completo = True
            break

        if num == 2:
            print()
            print("2 é primo.")
            print()
            completo = True
            break

        if einteiro == True:
            print()
            print("O número escolhido foi %d" % num)
            print()
            divisor = 2
            while divisor < num:

                teste = num % divisor
                divi = num / divisor

                if teste == 0:    
                    print("Este número não é primo! Ele conseguiu dividir pelo número %d, o resultado foi %d!" % (divisor, divi))
                    print()
                    completo = True
                    break

                if teste != 0: 
                    print()
                    print("Ele não divide por %d..." % divisor)
                    print()


            if divisor == num:
                print("Ele é primo!")
                print()
                completo = True 

        if einteiro == False:
            print("O número tem que ser inteiro!")

    while True:
        a = input("Deseja ir de novo? (y/n): ")
        if a in ('y', 'n'):
            if a == 'y':
                programa()

            else:
                print()
                print("Adeus :)")
                print("=" * 50) 
                sys.exit()

        else:
            print()
            print("Digitação Inválida!")
            print() 
            continue


programa()
```

Comment: Use o teorema de Rosser para encontrar o enésimo primo.

Comment: Creio que faltou incrementar a variável divisor em seu programa.

Comment: Pela definição de número natural primo:
- 1 não é primo;
- 2 é o unico natural par que é primo;
- se não existe nenhum número entre 2 e SQRT(n) que divida n então n é primo.
Com estas considerações você pode otimizar bastante seu código. 
De qualquer maneira não será a maneira mais otimizada de se determinar se um número é primo.

Comment: `int(qualquer coisa)` já retorna um `int`, não precisa usar `isinstance` depois. Pra saber se `int()` falhou, vc captura o `ValueError` - tem exemplo [na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). Valores booleanos podem ser testados diretamente: `if completo:` em vez de `if completo == True:`. Pra imprimir uma linha em branco, use `\n`, então no início poderia ser `print('\n{:=^55}'.format(''))` - o `\n` pula uma linha, e o formato `=^55` preenche com 55 caracteres `=` (veja exemplos em https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: De qq forma, algoritmo pra achar números primos é o que não falta na internet (inclusive [aqui no próprio site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+n%C3%BAmero+primo)). Alguns exemplos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231555/112052 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801391 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/18833759

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Função que retorna o menor número primo. Em PYTHON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191130/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-que-retorna-o-menor-n%c3%bamero-primo-em-python)

Answer (score 0):

Simplificação:

```
import sys

def programa():
    print("=" * 55)
    num = int(input("\nDigite um número para fazer o teste se o mesmo é primo: "))
    einteiro = isinstance(num, int)
    if num == 1:
        print("\n1 é primo.")
    elif num == 2:
        print("\n2 é primo.")
    else :
        einteiro == True ,print("\nO número escolhido foi %d" % num)


    def divisor(n):
        n=2
        teste = num % n
        divi = num / n
        if teste == 0:
            print("\nEste número não é primo! Ele conseguiu dividir pelo número %d, o resultado foi %d!" % (n, divi))
        elif teste != 0:
            print("\nEle não divide por %d..." % (n))
        elif n == num:
            print("\nEle é primo!")
        else:
            einteiro == False
            print("\nO número tem que ser inteiro!")

    a = input("Deseja ir de novo? (y/n): ")
    if a in ('y', 'n'):
        if a == 'y': programa()
        elif a=='n':
            print("\nAdeus")
            print('='*50)
        else:
            a!='n'or 'y'
            print("\nDigitação Inválida!")



programa()
```